# AppleScript, manipulate the return value from a one-liner tell-statement, still on the same line?

Tags: list, applescript, return-value, one-liner

```
tell application "Finder" to get bounds of window of desktop
```

returns something like

```
{0, 0, 1440, 900}
```

How can I do something like

```
get item 3 of (tell application "Finder" to get bounds of window of desktop)
```

still in the same line?

The tell statement clearly returns a list but when I try to access it like you access lists, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
tell application "Finder" to get item 3 of (get bounds of window of desktop)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder" to item 3 of (get bounds of window of desktop)
```

OR

```
tell application "Finder" to set thirdItem to item 3 of (get bounds of window of desktop)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner way would be to assign each item to a list of variables, like so:

```
tell application id ("com.apple.finder") ¬
        to set {X, Y, W, H} to the bounds ¬
        of the desktop's window
```

If you only need `W`, you can discard the other items by assigning them to a class element, such as `null` or `missing value`:

```
tell application id ("com.apple.finder") ¬
        to set {null, null, W, null} to ¬
        the bounds of the desktop's window
```

Comment: I need W and H as input to something else, and that is the only place I use these values, hence I want a oneliner.

Comment: @d-b These are **both** _one-liners_!